# Python Skips Numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a program that's supposed to determine the square root of a number by brute force. However, certain numbers(same every time).

Here is the code:

```
toCalc = 3

guess = toCalc
toCalc = round(toCalc, 2)
while 1+1==2:

        print "Trying ", guess, "..."
        calc = guess * guess
        calc = round(calc, 2)
        print calc
        guess = guess - 0.01
        if calc == toCalc:
                break
```

And here is the output:

```
Trying  1.22 ...
1.49
Trying  1.21 ...
1.46
Trying  1.2 ...
1.44
Trying  1.19 ...
1.42
Trying  1.18 ...
1.39
Trying  1.17 ...
1.37
Trying  1.16 ...
1.35
Trying  1.15 ...
1.32
Trying  1.14 ...
1.3
Trying  1.13 ...
1.28
Trying  1.12 ...
1.25
Trying  1.11 ...
1.23
Trying  1.1 ...
1.21
Trying  1.09 ...
1.19
Trying  1.08 ...
1.17
Trying  1.07 ...
1.14
Trying  1.06 ...
1.12
Trying  1.05 ...
1.1
Trying  1.04 ...
1.08
Trying  1.03 ...
1.06
Trying  1.02 ...
1.04
Trying  1.01 ...
1.02
Trying  1.0 ...
1.0
Trying  0.99 ...
0.98
Trying  0.98 ...
0.96
Trying  0.97 ...
0.94
Trying  0.96 ...
0.92
Trying  0.95 ...
0.9
Trying  0.94 ...
0.88
Trying  0.93 ...
0.86
Trying  0.92 ...
0.85
Trying  0.91 ...
0.83
```

The number under "Trying" is calc and the number after "Trying" is guess.

Comment: Why not just use math.sqrt

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Your algorithm does not work. Try to find a better one.

Comment: I don't see any numbers that are same every time

Comment: If you want an infinite loop, ``while True`` would be more standard

Comment: @TilakMaddy Because I was asked to use bruteforce.

Comment: @JamesElderfield: Actually, on Py2, you'd want `while 1:`; `True` isn't a keyword on Py2, so it has to be looked up on every loop (just in case someone decided to do `True = False` or something), the byte code compiler can't optimize it. `while 1:` compiles to an unconditional jump, no loading or testing required. Yes, it's dumb. Py3 fixed it thankfully (so `while True:` and `while 1:` both compile to unconditional jumps).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I did not know that, interesting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> round(1.73 * 1.73, 2)
2.99
>>> round(1.732 * 1.732, 2)
3.0
>>> round(1.74 * 1.74, 2)
3.03
```

9*9 = 81, 10*10 = 100 and we don't say numbers between 81 to 100 are skipped.

You are trying with 1.73 and 1.74, neither of them can produce exact value of 3 by squaring.

This behavior is "not skipping numbers", but it is all about the precision.

Floating point numbers are not that simple to deal. For this particular problem, using a difference of 0.001 solved the issue, but may not work for all other numbers.

However the below is code that solves the issue.

```
toCalc = 3 

guess = toCalc
toCalc = round(toCalc, 2)


while 1+1==2:

    print "Trying ", guess, "..."
    calc = guess * guess
    calc = round(calc, 2)
    print calc
    guess = guess - 0.001
    if calc == toCalc:
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

When you take the `next guess` which is `old guess - 0.01`, and square that, the `next square` is approximately `old square - 0.02` (using a binomic formula). This means the step in the guess squared column is about 0.02 and thus numbers are missing.

Is that what you meant?

A better algorithm might be to use bisection (google it).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shorter alternative. It only needs 5 steps to calculate 11 correct decimals of `sqrt(3)`, thanks to [Newton's iteration](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsIteration.html) :

```
to_calc = 3
guess = to_calc
epsilon = 1e-13

while abs(guess**2 > to_calc) > epsilon:
    guess = 0.5*(guess + to_calc / guess)

print(guess)
# 1.73205080757
print(guess**2)
# 3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully sure of what you are asking but the following function uses an exhaustive approximation solution. It does the following:

- start with exhaustive enumeration
- take small steps to generate guesses
- check to see if you are close enough

```
def squareRootExhaustive(x, epsilon):
 """Assumes x and epsilon are positive floats & epsilon < 1."""

    # x = number for which to calculate the square root
    # epsilon = how close you want to get to the answer

    increment = epsilon**2 # Number of steps it will take to find a good enough approximation

    guess = 0.0 # start the answer at 0

    # while the difference between guess ^ 2 and the num 'x', for which 
    # we are trying to find the square root of, is greater or equals epsilon 
    # and guess * guess is less or equals x, increment the answer
    while abs(guess**2 - x) >= epsilon and guess*guess <= x:
        # print(ans)to check the number of exhaustive guesses it generates 
        # before returning the most accurate answer  
        guess += increment 
        if guess*guess > x:
           raise ValueError
    return "{} is the sqaure root of {}".format(round(guess, 2), x)

squareRootExhaustive(3, 0.01)
```

Lower values of epsilon will give more accurate answers but will slow the program. Larger values will give faster answers but they will be less accurate.

This algorithm will have complexity issues. That is why bisection algorithm is better.